# Stackwalker within try-catch block java 9

Tags: java, java-9

I am trying to print stack walker in exception block but it is displaying only current class

```
public class Test1 {
    public void test() throws Exception{
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
        test2.test();
    }
}
```

```
public class Test2 {
    public void test() throws Exception{
        System.out.println(1/0);
    }
}
```

```
public class TestStackWalker {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        try {
            test1.test();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           StackWalker stack = StackWalker.getInstance();
           stack.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are calling this StackWalker from main method directly so what did you expect? Maybe you wanted [`Throwable::getStackTrace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace--)

Comment: you can do the same thing in `test()` method you will see the stack `StackWalker.getInstance().forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`StackWalker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html) docs :

> The walk method opens a sequential stream of `StackFrames` for the current thread and then applies the given function to walk the `StackFrame` stream.

Since you are calling it from your main method - there is only one `StackFrame` allocated and is being printed :

```
TestStackWalker.main(TestStackWalker.java:10)
```

If you want have access to each stack element of you exception's stack trace - use [`Throwable::getStackTrace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace--) which returns array of `StackTraceElement` :

```
class TestStackWalker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        try {
            test1.test();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Arrays.stream(e.getStackTrace()).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

which will print :

```
Test2.test(Test2.java:3)
Test1.test(Test1.java:4)
TestStackWalker.main(TestStackWalker.java:7)
```

If you want only to print it [`Throwable::printStackTrace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--) should be enough.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` should just be sufficient for that instead.